# SharePoint 2010 calculated column getting stuck half way through the formula

Tags: 2010, column, calculated-column-formula

Here is a formula I am using to get the RAG status to display either "Green" "Yellow" "Amber" "Red" in a calculated column, it works fine for green but when entering the data in a form the value won't go past yellow, I am hoping somebody can help me, here is the formula

```
=IF([Form Score]<3,"Green", IF(OR([Form Score]>4,[Form Score]<7),"Yellow", IF(OR([Form Score]>8, [Form Score]<14),"Amber", IF([Form Score]>15,"Red"))))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Issue with your formula is that - for `OR` condition of Yellow, one of the condition was always true (i.e. Form score >4) hence it was returning Yellow as output every time.

Solution -  Replace `OR` with `AND`.

P.S. You are missing some condition like [Form Score] equal to 3,4,7,8,14,15.

Comment: Hi, thanks that works but I have come across the issue where the numbers change i.e. 0-3 Green 4-7 Yellow, so if I get a score of 4 I should get "Yellow" I now get "NO" I tried the Unicode Character for "is equal to or less than" but SP does not like the character?

Comment: This is what I have now :

Comment: =IF([Form Score]<3,"Green", IF(AND([Form Score]>4,[Form Score]<8),"Yellow", IF(AND([Form Score]>8, [Form Score]<15),"Amber", IF(AND([Form Score]>15,[Form Score]<80),"Red"))))

Comment: use "<=" or ">=" as required.